# Comparing Folder names from different directories and outputting both results in csv - PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have two directories "A" and "B". "A" has folders abc,def,ghi,jkl in it and "B" has ghi,jkl,mno in it. I need output as below in Csv:-

[image]

I am new to PowerShell so googled about folders comparison and wrote below script

```
$SourceFolder = "A"
$ArchiveFolder = "B"

$Folder1 = Get-childitem $SourceFolder
$Folder2 = Get-childitem $ArchiveFolder

Compare-Object $Folder1 $Folder2 -PassThru
```

But the above code is just giving the differences but not in the format needed above.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow is not a code-writing service, so to get help, please edit your question to include specific steps you're having issues with.

Comment: Just need to compare at folder level like in above e.g abc,def is folder and only comparison that needs to be made is on folder name.. no size contraint.. folder name should be same in both directories and even if they are not then also they should come up in the result

Comment: What if a `filename` exists in both directories but the e.g. the `Size` is different (I presume that show both files but an `N` in the `Matching` column)

Comment: We just need comparison at folder level and if folder names are same then show both directories folder names and Y as matching.. else N.. and comparison should only be on name .. nothing on size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question, this could be one way of doing this:

```
$SourceFolder  = "X:\A"
$ArchiveFolder = "X:\B"

$Folder1 = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Directory
$Folder2 = Get-ChildItem -Path $ArchiveFolder -Directory

$result = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Folder1 -DifferenceObject $Folder2 -Property Name -IncludeEqual |
            Sort-Object 'SideIndicator' | ForEach-Object {
                $folder = $_.Name
                switch ($_.SideIndicator) {
                    '<=' { $a = $folder; $b = $null;   $m = 'N' }
                    '==' { $a = $folder; $b = $folder; $m = 'Y' }
                    '=>' { $a = $null;   $b = $folder; $m = 'N' }
                }
                [PsCustomObject]@{'A'= $a ; 'B' = $b; 'Matching' = $m }
            }

#output on screen
$result

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\TheOutput.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output on screen:

```
A   B   Matching
-   -   --------
abc     N       
def     N       
ghi ghi Y       
jkl jkl Y       
    mno N
```

Comment: Thanks!! this works like a charm.. one more thing I am getting unsorted records in csv .. I tried to do this $result |Sort-Object | Export-Csv -Path .. but it didn't help

Comment: @Himsy The result is sorted by SideIndicator, so first are all folders under `A`, then `B`. Perhaps you need to sort the folders first": `$Folder1 = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Directory | Sort-Object Name`. Same for $Folder2. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Thanks.. I removed sorting from SideIndicator and added to both the Folders and it worked.

Comment: @Himsy Good to hear you have the sorting fixed the way you want it. Well done!